# How to add Views dynamically or on top of other components?

Tags: android, layout, view

I use a `LinearLayout` and first I have a `MapView` and below the map I have a `TableLayout` with informations fields.

Now I would like to add additional information fields (e.g. a new `TableLayout`) when the user select a specific menu item on the Options Menu. I would like to have these fields either between the `MapView` and the `TableLayout`, or on top of the bottom area of the `MapView`.

How can I add this `TableLayout` with additional information fields dynamically after the user has selected a menu item? How can I show it below the `MapView` or on top of the bottom area of the `MapView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [ViewStubs](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-stubs.html) for hidden on-demand view. If you need to display something on top of other view, you can use another container to hold the MapView and the stub, FrameLayout could be a good candidate.